# Audio File not playing Android

Tags: android, audio, intellij-idea, libgdx

I am having trouble playing audio files. I am currently learning how to develop with android and libgdx. So i created this code to play an mp3 when the application opens. But it does not play at all. I keep getting the log below.

Code:

```
package com.soundfx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class SoundFx extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Sound sound;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Smile.mp3"));
        sound.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
    }
}
```

Log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFOJi.jpg

I also get Sample rate (96000) out of range

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the sample rate of your file (down to 44100 Hz for instance). You can convert your sound file using one of the various software tools available, or even online converters.

Also bear in mind that the Sound class is only meant for small audio files, such as short sound effects, as the file will be entirely loaded into memory (please refer to [Sound](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Sound.html)). If the MP3 you are playing is actually a whole song, use the Music class instead to stream the audio file ([Music](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html)).

Comment: ok cool thanks for the response. I was trying different files but ill try lowering the sample rate then. I can probably do that with audacity right???

Comment: Yes, Audacity will do the job for instance!